# How to retrieve data from internal storage in a FragmentActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, internal-storage

Hi everyone I'm currently developing an android app that writes a JSON data to internal storage and it should be retrieve from a **class** that extends **FragmentActivity**.

This is the code on how I write the data to the internal storage:

```
private void createFile(String data) throws IOException{
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("userObj", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(data.getBytes());
    fos.close();
}
```

and when I'm retrieving the data from a **class** that extends **Activity**
I **CAN** read the data like this

```
private void readFile() throws IOException, JSONException {

     FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("userObj");
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
     StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();

     while (bis.available() != 0){
        char c = (char) bis.read();
        b.append(c);
     }

     bis.close();
     fis.close();
     JSONObject data = new JSONObject(b.toString());
     Log.d(Constants.DATA,  data.getString("qr_code_png"));
}
```

but when I'm retrieving the data from a **class** that extends a **FragmentActivity** with the same code I **Cannot retrieve**:

```
  public void readFile() throws IOException, JSONException {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("userObj");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        while (bis.available() != 0){
            char c = (char) bis.read();
            b.append(c);
        }
        bis.close();
        fis.close();
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(b.toString());
        Log.d(Constants.DATA,  data.getString("qr_code_png"));

    }
```

How can I retrieve the saved data from internal storage from a class that extends fragment activity?

Comment: what has retrieving got to do with fragment activity?. Its the base class for support based fragments.

Comment: have you given permission to read write external/internal storage ?

Comment: Why not use SharedPreferences instead ? More easy to manage and you don't need the storage permission.

Comment: I am able to write data to internal storage, and retrieve the save data using a class that extends activity. And because I'm using Android's Navigation Drawer my MainActivity.class now extends FragmentActivity.

Comment: I am getting Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to save raw JSON data? It might be better to parse it out into a database. How large is the JSON you are writing to storage?